# Laravel On-Demand Notification with CC

Tags: php, laravel

I'm sending notifications using the facade and it works well for addressing multiple 'to' emails however I need to be able to CC someone else in.

`Notification::route('mail', ['user1@domain.com', 'user2@domain.com'])->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice));`

I am hoping to address user1, and cc user2.  Is it possible with the notification facade?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose a solution (not as elegant as I would want), is to include the cc into the array that is passed and then define it in the MailMessage().

`$data = array('name' => 'User Name', 'count' => 6, 'body' => 'My str', 'cc' = > 'user2@domain.com');`

On the Notification

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $cc = $this->data['cc'];

return (new MailMessage)
                    ->cc($cc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the user to be cc-ed through the constructor. Let's call it $user2:

`$user1->notify(new InvoicePaid($invoice, $user2));`

In your notification:

```
    public function __construct($invoice, User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->cc($this->user->email)
                    ...
    }
```